# not able to get form post data in controller in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new in node js and I'm facing an issue in node implementation. I want to get node form post data in the controller but I am unable to find the solution for that. here is my code.

This is my route.

```
app.route('/login')
.get(loginController.login)
.post(loginController.loginPost).all(methodNotAllowedHandler);
```

This is my loginController

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
    res.render('login/login');
    };


// To get the username and password
exports.loginPost = function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.password;
    console.log(email);
    return false;
};
```

this is from login.ejs file

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/login">
```

please help me with this how can I get the values of email and password to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake so I thought I should tell this to everyone.

```
// To get the username and password
exports.loginPost = function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

if(email == "abc@123.in" && password == "abc@123.com") {
    var response = {status : 200 ,message : "Login Successful" , data : [] };
    return res.status(200).json(response);
} else {
    var response = {status : 200 ,message : "Login Failed" , data : [] };
    return res.status(200).json(response);
}
```

Comment: The only difference I see is a typo ( req.body.password instead of req.password ), and you don't even explain that in your answer but let people compare two blocks of code. Either explain the solution and what you made wrong in the first place or just remove question and answer. Like this nobody can learn anything from this post.